# Netty TooLongFrameException: How is the length computed?

Tags: java, netty, vert.x

I have a test server and a client application. Server is built with `Vert.x 3.2.1` (users Netty 4.0.33.Final) and client with `Apache httpclient 4.5.1`.

Have configured server to accept `maxHeaderSize` as 8KB. As I send requests from client I see that requests bearing header sizes of around 3KB starts failing with below exception on server.

> io.netty.handler.codec.TooLongFrameException: HTTP header is larger than 8192 bytes

Sharing the server and client code for reference.

**Server:**

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Vertx vertx = Vertx.vertx();
        HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions();
        options.setMaxHeaderSize(1024*8);
        HttpServer httpServer = (HttpServer) vertx.createHttpServer(options );
        httpServer.requestHandler(req -> {
            System.out.println(req.headers().names());
            for(String h : req.headers().names()){
                System.out.println(h+": "+req.headers().get(h).length()+": "+(h.length()+req.headers().get(h).length()));
            }
            req.response().setStatusCode(200).end();
        });
        httpServer.listen(6565);

    }
```

**Client:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        CloseableHttpClient httpclient = HttpClients.custom().build();
        HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://localhost:6565");
        String headerValue = generateHeader(3045);
        get.addHeader("myheader", headerValue);
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(get);
        String resp = IOUtils.toString(response.getEntity().getContent());
        System.out.println(response.getStatusLine());
        httpclient.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

`generateHeader()` is a method that generates a String of specified length - when input with 3, result is "aaa".

Apache http client also adds some more headers - Host, Connection, User-Agent and Accept-Encoding. Along with all these, The behavior I notice is that the server fails when I pass 3045 or above as input to `generateHeader()`, but succeeds for any lower value.

Though configured is 8k, I fail to understand why failures occur for such lower values.

Answer (score 0):

This may be a bug in Netty. Please open a bug-report in Netty issue tracker and provide details how to reproduce it:

https://github.com/netty/netty/issues